# Search for single punctuation character (full-text indexed basex)

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, basex

There is an entity in my basex database that basically looks like this (I added wrapping):

```xml
<Paragraph>
  mRNA made from thyroid carcinoma, cDNA made by oligo-dT  priming. 
  Non-directionally cloned into UDG sites. Size-selected on  agarose gel, average insert 
    size 500 bp. 
  Primary library.  cDNA Library Preparation: David B. Krizman, Ph.D. | |
</Paragraph>
```

The database started out as a 45 GB xml file, but thanks to basex full-text indexing, it takes less than 1 second to find it with

`/BioSampleSet/BioSample/Description/Comment/Paragraph[text() contains text "mRNA made from thyroid carcinoma"]`

I would like to find `<Paragraph>`s that contain the vertical pipe character `|`, but

`/BioSampleSet/BioSample/Description/Comment/Paragraph[text() contains text "|"]` is optimized as `()` and instantaneously returns 0 hits.

Searching for `"\|"` or `"\\|"` doesn't help either.

Comment: Does `"\|"` instead of `"|"` work?

Comment: Shoot, I should have mentioned that. No, neither "\|" or "\\|" helps.

Comment: I do not have BaseX installed to test, but if there is an issue interpreting the pipe will the hex sequence work in this situation? `...contains text "&#x7C;"`  (hex 7C = '|')

Comment: @DavidDenenberg great idea, but no that doesn't help.

Comment: Yeah, I was digging some more and found this.  Doesn't sound promising: https://mailman.uni-konstanz.de/pipermail/basex-talk/2018-January/012881.html